How do I Fix this blue color and ramdomized coloring on donut icing
I am currently learning blender as a beginner with blender guru tutorial and I came up with an issue with random color on incing on second donut and also there is some other issue also persist with color or icing which has to be all pink but still there are some blue color showing in darker side of both donuts.
I am attaching file link for your reference https://easyupload.io/vy6wez
I also changed positions of light source but the blue and green color remains in the same positions.
I think it is related to do with some sub surface scattering.
Please help me to fix this I am also attaching some images of that.
But I am unable to fix it.

As showing in image below I am talking about those blue and green colors.

Hi and welcome. In it's current form your questions is related to using Blender purely to model and doesn't involve anything related to programming/scripting (e.g. Blender's Python API). Stackoverflow focuses on programming. I warmly recommend using https://blender.stackexchange.com for this particular question instead.

Can a moderator please migrate this to https://blender.stackexchange.com/ where it's best suited ?
(Sorry, I wish the migrate to other sites menu system had an autocomplete for all stackexchange sites, not just the handful currently available). Thank you so much.
